# How to check if a file exists based on CRC32 from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

My current batch file is:

```
if exist "C:\program\config.ini" goto :step1
if not exist "C:\program\config.ini" goto :step2
```

It works like that, but I want to check the CRC32/MD5 of that "config.ini" file to see if it match up with a certain CRC32/MD5 number, a utility like [crc32.exe](http://esrg.sourceforge.net/utils_win_up/md5sum/) could be helpful to achieve that.

thus I want the batch file to work like:

```
if "C:\program\config.ini" equals CRC32 K136AM82 goto :step1
if not "C:\program\config.ini" equals CRC32 K136AM82 goto :step2
```

Comment: You need to generate the checksum first and assign it to a variable. Then you can use the `IF` command to compare the calculated checksum to a predefined checksum. I would invite you to take a look at [HashSum.bat](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7592). That may make it easier for you.

Comment: You could use [`certutil -hashfile`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html) to compute the MD5 hash…

Comment: Realize that there's a 1/65536 chance that two different files could generate the same CRC32.

Comment: I'll be using MD5 then MarkRansom, using "HashSum.bat" worked, thx Squashman, aschipfl